# Who is Jesus talking to?

Tags: jesus

Who was Jesus talk to in
Matthew 20:18-20? Talking to us today or just the living apostles at that time ? Explain Your answer so I will know what yall are meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  In order to understand what we look for in well-researched questions (such as actually quoting the text in full), please take our Tour: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is found in verse 17 of Matthew chapter 20:

> Now as Jesus was going up to Jerusalem, ***he took the twelve disciples aside and said to them***.......

The recorded words in Matthew's gospel are there to inform us (today) of what Jesus said back then to his disciples.

The answer, taken directly from the Bible, is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The text of Matt 20:17-19 says this:

> **17** As Jesus was going up to Jerusalem, **He took the twelve disciples aside and said**, **18** “Look, we are going up to
> Jerusalem, and the Son of Man will be delivered over to the chief
> priests and scribes. They will condemn Him to death **19** and will
> deliver Him over to the Gentiles to be mocked and flogged and
> crucified. And on the third day He will be raised to life.”

Note that the text of Matt 20:17 explicitly says that Jesus was talking to the 12 disciples surrounding Him at the time.  In fact, the BSB helpfully supplies a heading for this little section of Matthew (correctly) saying:

> The Third Prediction of the Passion

Comment: I have no idea why anyone would down-vote your answer, so I up-voted it (since I said basically the same as you).  (:

Comment: Thank you @Lesley - I am mystified why some downvote here as well - I would prefer that the system insist on an explanation for downvoting.  I very rarely downvote even when I disagree with the answer - Downvotes should be reserved for answers that a demonstrably factually wrong.